# Trying to implement Jekyll via the Poole/lanyon but formatting is not appearing

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I'm currently working through my first implementation of a Jekyll webpage (via Github-pages) and I'm trying to use the Poole: Lanyon structure. However, while it seems that the static site is active, it is not picking up any of the formatting.

I can't tell if I needed to add anything else from lanyon github page (https://github.com/poole/lanyon) or if it could have something to do with my '_config' file, which currently looks as follows (or is an entirely different issue):

```
title:               Michael
tagline:             'hopefully a blog2'
description:         'A reserved <a href="https://jekyllrb.com" target="_blank">Jekyll</a> theme that places the utmost gravity on content with a hidden drawer. Made by <a href="https://twitter.com/mdo" target="_blank">@mdo</a>.'
url:                 "/michaelmarzec.github.io"
baseurl:             "https://michaelmarzec.github.io"
paginate:            5
permalink:           pretty

# About/contact
author:
  name:              Mark Otto
  url:               https://twitter.com/mdo
  email:             markdotto@gmail.com

# Gems
plugins:
  - jekyll-paginate

# Custom vars
version:             1.1.0
google_analytics_id: #UA-XXXX-Y
```

My github repository is here: https://github.com/michaelmarzec/michaelmarzec.github.io

And the attempted website here: https://michaelmarzec.github.io/

Any recommendations or advice will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was overthinking this issue - the following was my simple solution:

```
 url:                 https://michaelmarzec.github.io/
 baseurl:             ''
```