# Jekyll Lanyon not rendering styles in GitHub Pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

Styles are not rendered on [my GitHub Pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXJnG.jpg).

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68107198/19374566). But the solution doesn't work for me. I've tried a lot of things with my _config.yaml url and base urls, but it won't work. The minima theme works fine though, somehow.

Refer to my GitHub [issue](https://github.com/poole/lanyon/issues/309) (basically the same content), [repository](https://github.com/I7T5/i7t5.github.io) (the gh-pages branch), and the un-rendered [website](https://i7t5.github.io).

Everything seems fine on my localhost:4000 when I do `Jekyll serve`.

Here's my _config.yaml

```
# Setup
title:               From Ina
tagline:             ''
description:         'Hello, world! Welcome to my very first website : D'
url:                 http://i7t5.github.io
baseurl:             ''
paginate:            5
permalink:           pretty

# About/contact
author:
  name:              Ina Tang
  url:               https://github.com/I7T5
  email:             inatang75@outlook.com

# Gems
plugins:
  - jekyll-paginate

# Custom vars
version:             0.0.1
google_analytics_id: #UA-XXXX-Y
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved when I replaced the following 'absolute_url' to 'relative_url' in root/_includes/head.html

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ '/public/css/poole.css' | absolute_url }}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ '/public/css/syntax.css' | absolute_url }}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ '/public/css/lanyon.css' | absolute_url }}">
```

But I don't understand why the favicons showed up fine with absolute_url